# RRD dynamic data source

Tags: nagios, rrd

I using Nagios with custom check that will return performance data which I need for graph. Number of performance data can be different overtime.
Performance data are stored in RRD and everything works good, but if number of performance data is different from first check, then RRD show this error in log:

```
expected 4 data source readings (got 3) from 1468937373:40.00:10.00:10.00
```

and graph don´t work anymore...

My RRD using GAUGE as data source, is problem there?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out!
I must set in RRD config value RRD_STORAGE_TYPE from `SINGLE` to `MULTIPLE` and now works almost perfect.